# Creating a TFS Custom "Builds" Check-In Policy

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, azure-devops, tfs-2015

The built-in TFS Builds Check-In Policy isn't configurable - it just looks to see if the last build failed, and if so, it shows the Policy warning in Visual Studio. Unfortunately, it considers the "last" build to be the one that last finished in time, not the last one to finish with the most recent changeset. As a result, it's possible for the Policy to be Clear even though things are broken. Consider this scenario:

Joe commits code in Changeset 1234 and it starts build "Awesome Build"
John commits code in Changeset 1235 and it starts build "Awesome Build" as well, but change set 1235 contains a break

Since I have multiple build agents, both builds run at the same time.

Now let's say John's build finishes first and fails because of the break - the build policy is now in a Broken state - warning that you can't checkin (as expected).

Joe's build finishes second and succeeds - the build policy at this point will revert to a clear state, and no warning will appear. (not expected, the last changeset is still broken and needs to be fixed).

I know TFS allows me to create my own custom check-in policies by compiling a class implementing 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.PolicyBase'. There are some questions here though:

1. The only OFFICIAL documentation I could find is here (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668980.aspx) and as the page suggests, this content is deprecated and no longer maintained. Does this imply there is a new/better/easier way to implement a custom check-in policy?
2. Does anyone know where I can find documentation pertaining to writing these policies, specifically a "Builds" policy to solve the problem I outlined above. I'd like my check-in policy to be enforced base on latest changeset, not most recent build time.

Any help you can give would be great. This policy fix will fix up a lot of headaches in my very large development group.

Comment: Why not just use a gated check-in (TFVC) or pull requests+branch policies (Git) instead? Check-in policies are a pain to maintain and distribute and can easily be circumvented by either not using Visual Studio, or by deleting the policy assembly entirely.

Comment: TFS Gated check-ins would work, but it burdens our already taxed build agents and would add more overhead than we're prepared to introduce.

I'd prefer Git, but we're not prepared to change VC systems yet. I am not a fan of check-in policies either, but this is the task I'm asked to solve. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

The article you provided is the simple and better way and it is applied to higher version, the register key path is according to the version of VS (8.0, 12.0 etc…), for 64 bit machine, the path likes HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio{VisualStudioVersion}\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Checkin Policies.

In your custom check-in policy, you could check latest build result through TFS API (Evaluate method). For example:

```
TeamFoundationServer tfs = new TeamFoundationServer("http://tfsserver:8080/tfs"); 
IBuildServer buildServer = (IBuildServer) tfs.GetService(typeof(IBuildServer)); 
IBuildDetailSpec buildDetailSpec = buildServer.CreateBuildDetailSpec("Team Project", "Build Definition Name"); 
buildDetailSpec.MaxBuildsPerDefinition = 1; 
buildDetailSpec.QueryOrder = BuildQueryOrder.FinishTimeDescending; 
IBuildQueryResult results = buildServer.QueryBuilds(buildDetailSpec);
```

If you just need to make sure changes haven't the issue (build can be succeed), as Daniel said that using gated check-in (TFVC) or pull request with branch policies (git) instead.